# CoreMidi.framework sending midi commands

Tags: objective-c, macos, midi

there is an app called FreeStyler, that you can control using midi commands. In my mac app I want to send midi signals.

Can someone show an example of this?

Elijah

Answer (score 3):

This is what it took to send a note to my blofeld synth. I hope it helps. You can use MIDIObjectGetProperties to find the uniqueIDs for all the midi devices connected to your mac.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import <CoreMIDI/CoreMIDI.h>

MIDIEndpointRef getEndpointWithUniqueID(MIDIUniqueID id){

    MIDIObjectRef endPoint;

    MIDIObjectType foundObj;

    MIDIObjectFindByUniqueID(id, &endPoint, &foundObj);

    return (MIDIEndpointRef) endPoint;

}

MIDIClientRef getMidiClient(){

    MIDIClientRef midiClient;

    NSString *outPortName =@"blofeldOut";

    MIDIClientCreate((CFStringRef)outPortName, NULL, NULL, &midiClient);

    return midiClient;

}

MIDIPortRef getOutPutPort(){

    MIDIPortRef outPort;

    NSString *outPortName =@"blofeldOut";

    MIDIOutputPortCreate(getMidiClient(), (CFStringRef)outPortName, &outPort);

    return outPort;

}

MIDIPacketList getMidiPacketList(){

    MIDIPacketList packetList;

    packetList.numPackets = 1;

    MIDIPacket* firstPacket = &packetList.packet[0];

    firstPacket->timeStamp = 0; // send immediately

    firstPacket->length = 3;

    firstPacket->data[0] = 0x90;

    firstPacket->data[1] = 60;

    firstPacket->data[2] = 64;

    // TODO: add end note sequence

    return packetList;

}

void play_note(void) {

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; 

    MIDIPacketList packetList=getMidiPacketList();

    MIDIUniqueID blofeldEndpointID = -934632258;

    MIDIEndpointRef blofeldEndpoint = getEndpointWithUniqueID(blofeldEndpointID);

    MIDISend(getOutPutPort(), blofeldEndpoint, &packetList);

    MIDIEndpointDispose(blofeldEndpoint);

    [pool drain];

}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    play_note();

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your application will need to use the CoreMIDI framework to send or receive MIDI, which I can tell you from experience is not a lot of fun to work with directly.  You might want to try the [vvopensource](http://code.google.com/p/vvopensource/) framework, which is a MIDI framework designed for cocoa.